# Missing unknown value in gcloud builds submit

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to run a cloud build on my GCP project:

```
gcloud builds submit src --tag=eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT>/<APP_NAME>:latest --gcs-source-staging-dir=<BUILD_BUCKET>/runstage --gcs-log-dir=<BUILD_BUCKET>/logs --project=<PROJECT>
```

This worked fine yesterday but now I get:

`ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) value for field [bucket] in collection [storage.objects] is required but was not provided`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you have changed your credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue and I also got the same error. I resolved it by using the following command:

```
gcloud builds submit --gcs-source-staging-dir="gs://<BUILD_BUCKET>/runstage" --gcs-log-dir="gs://<BUILD_BUCKET>/logs" --tag=eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT>/<APP_NAME>:latest  --project=<PROJECT>
```

Make sure to call Dockerfile explicitly in your cloudbuild.yaml file. For example :

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT>/<APP_NAME>:latest', ‘-f’, 'Dockerfile' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `gs://` before the name of your bucket.